Determine bytes per inode ratio of existing ext4 filesystem
I created a filesystem following this guide: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Ext4#Create_a_new_ext4_filesystem
However it looks like I made a mistake because the ratio for /dev/sdc doesn't add up:
asdf@pve:~# df -i
Filesystem               Inodes  IUsed      IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda2            2953572160 622647 2952949513    1% /mnt/my8tb
/dev/sdb1             183148544 102711  183045833    1% /mnt/my3tb
/dev/sdc                1907840   3584    1904256    1% /mnt/my2tb

asdf@pve:~# df
Filesystem            1K-blocks       Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2            7814008828 5995014812 1818994016  77% /mnt/my8tb
/dev/sdb1            2883129520 1237379688 1499220196  46% /mnt/my3tb
/dev/sdc             1951774200 1277927944  576154144  69% /mnt/my2tb

I created it to be a largefile4 drive, but it didn't seem to work - 2 TB for this amount of inodes comes to around 1 MB per inode. (and again) I would expect ~4MB per inode in largefile4. Am I interpreting these results correctly?

This is missing the "df" output that shows how large these filesystems are...

FWIW, I can't seem to set an exact inode ratio. sudo mkfs.ext4 -i 9100263 /dev/sda and -i 11100263 both ended up with 357712 inodes on a 3TB drive. I assume there's rounding in the source code.

No, it isn't possible to specify an exact inode ratio, since there need to be a multiple of a full blocks of inodes for each group (e.g. 4096 bytes/block / 256 bytes/inode = 16 inodes/block).  You can also use -N total_inode_count to specify an inode count, but it will similarly be rounded to have at least one block of inodes per group.  For 3TiB / 128 MiB/group = 24576 groups, that is a minimum 24576 groups x 16 inodes/block (x 1 block/group) = 393216 inodes, so your 357712 number must be for a "short" 3TB.  Having a few extra inodes is not the end of the world...

I agree.  Your results look consistent with largefile, not largefile4.
Tested on Ubuntu 22.04, using a space-efficient "sparse file":
$ truncate -s 2TB t
$ mkfs.ext4 -T largefile4 t

$ sudo mount -o loop t /mnt

$ df -i /mnt
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/loop24    476864    11 476853    1% /mnt

$ df /mnt
Filesystem      1K-blocks  Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop24    1951742384    28 1854069724   1% /mnt

$ echo $((1951742384 * 1024 / 476864))
4191098

$ sudo umount /mnt
$ trash t


I agree, it looks like /dev/sdc was created with -T largefile.  If this is consistently using 1MB/inode with -T largefile4 on the OP's system, it seems possible (though I don't know why) that /etc/mke2fs.conf is messed up and using inode_ratio = 1048576 instead of inode_ratio = 4194304?
